# Combine two dataframes containing boolean values with "OR" logic

Tags: r

I can't find the answer and the simple approaches I've tried haven't worked.
Basically, I have two corresponding dataframes with identical dimensions, full of boolean values.

I want "OR" logic, to produce a third corresponding dataframe with a TRUE anywhere either starting dataframes had TRUE.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(T,T),
                  b=c(F,F))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(F,T),
                  b=c(F,T))
```

Desired output:

```
        a     b
[1,] TRUE FALSE
[2,] TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: For the future, please include reproducible examples of your data and your desired output. I've added it here since it was a simple example, but usually questions with out a [mcve] will get downvoted and closed

Comment: As simple as `df1 | df2`.

Answer (score 3):

It works using the `|` operator:

```
df1 | df2

        a     b
[1,] TRUE FALSE
[2,] TRUE  TRUE
```